# How can I detect a user's input language using Ruby without using an online service?

Tags: ruby, offline, language-detection

I'm looking for a library or technique to detect the input language of blocks of text provided by users. Online lookups (like Google translate) won't work for this task as I'm writing an app which must run offline.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I've found http://rubygems.org/gems/kenwaln-whatlanguage, which is performing excellently.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two more *n-gram*-based gems you might want to try. They work offline.

- https://github.com/echen/unsupervised-language-identification, optimized for separating english and other languages (has a live demo)
- https://github.com/feedbackmine/language_detector, less specialized, will detect more languages. Some languages may need some extra training — I found it to be not precise enough for German text.

Comment: The first one gives me `камон is English`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [CLD](https://github.com/jtoy/cld) which I really like, succinct and easy to use. Give it a try.

Comment: yes! i'm too but this version https://github.com/BanjoInc/cld2 - offline tool that works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

A quick demo of WhatLanguage in Ruby:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNqZ2cqOReo&list=UUJ_3fstMOH-g4yBxtvgAWkw&index=0&feature=plcp