# How to detect the language of a given text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, language-detection

In my Rails 3 application, users may write messages in forum. I would like to identify what the language is for a given message. I'm interested in English, Russian, and Hebrew languages. Is there any built-in library in Ruby/Rails for such a task? If not, any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: here good answers too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285511/how-can-i-detect-a-users-input-language-using-ruby-without-using-an-online-serv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this: https://github.com/nashby/wtf_lang

```
"ruby is so awesome!".lang # => "en"
"ruby is so awesome!".full_lang # => "ENGLISH"
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is something similar that can translate one language to other and uses Google translator ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the api provided by google to guess it with google translate.

See here for documentation : http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/using_rest_langdetect.html

Comment: There is no "Using Ruby" section there :(

Comment: Oh, in that case you'll have to use Java...
Sorry, couldn't resist :).
It has a JSON interface. You can generate and parse JSON easily with Ruby.

Comment: In fact, there are just examples, you have to anyway parse the JSON in every language. In ruby, you can use this : http://developer.yahoo.com/ruby/ruby-json.html

Comment: Not the best solution. Google has rate limits. There's a dependency on a 3rd party.. you want to limit those as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're concerned with languages with different character sets you could dig up the character codes that are predominantly in your strings. You could then see if they fall into the code sets that represent hebrew / cryllic characters.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could look at the [whatlanguage](https://github.com/peterc/whatlanguage) gem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog
http://blog.kenweiner.com/2008/04/server-side-language-detection-with.html
This may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

[Language Detection API](http://detectlanguage.com) provides [Ruby GEM](https://github.com/detectlanguage/detect_language) to detect language.

Comment: Looks interesting. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick demo of WhatLanguage for anyone interested :  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNqZ2cqOReo&list=UUJ_3fstMOH-g4yBxtvgAWkw&index=0&feature=plcp

Answer (score 0):

http://rubygems.org/gems/prose Prose dose it without a gem. Try it.