# Ruby Rails Gem to detect other language

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a gem to detect if a language is non-english?

I need to pass in a string and if it is not english, return an appropriate value.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285511/how-can-i-detect-a-users-input-language-using-ruby-without-using-an-online-serv

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem for the Google translate API, that handles, among other things, language detection. It's a paid service though: https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/libraries

Answer (score 2):

[WhatLanguage gem](https://github.com/peterc/whatlanguage) is your best bet. But it is not perfect, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [CLD](https://github.com/jtoy/cld) which I really like, succinct and easy to use, give it a try.